# Load store data with ajax call which requires complex types as arguments?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I know .net and javascript, but am a noob in sencha. I am working on application with sencha touch 2.0 on the client and asp.net web api on the server. I need to display a list of items (bills) to a user.

Currently, the server side api is of the form:

```
GetList(int userId, string[] locationsIds, ...) { ... }
```

In the client the store has 'autoLoad : false'. I call setExtraParams on the store's proxy as follows:

```
billStore.getProxy().setExtraParams({
    userId: getUserId(),                        //someFunction
    locationIds: getUserSelectedLocations(),    //someOtherFunction
});
```

But this adds the parameters to the query string (p.s: and I haven't manged to get it to work yet). I think having this in the request body makes more sense (similar to form submit using http post).

I have the following questions:

1. how do i achieve this?
2. What happens when i have complex types in the server side api? (note: this will be needed soon since asp.net web api support only a single complex type, so i will have to refactor 'arguments to class' anyway)?
3. Is this the recommended method?

complete code follows:

store:

```
Ext.define('noobapp.store.Bills',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
config: {
    storeId: 'billStore',
    model: 'noobapp.model.Bill',
    sorter: 'BillFrom',     
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'http://localhost/noobapis/api/bill/outstanding',
        reader: 'json'
    }
}
});
```

controller:

```
_fetchOutstandingBills : function(data){
    console.log(data);

    var me = faomobile.app.getController('noobapis.controller.Main');
    var billStore = Ext.getStore('billStore');
    if(!billStore) billStore = Ext.create('noobapis.store.Bills');

    billStore.getProxy().setExtraParams({
        userId: getUserId(), 
        locationIds: getUserSelectedLocations(),
    });

    billStore.load();
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give

```
method: 'POST'
```

in proxy config because by default it uses GET and thus send everything in URL.

You can also send complex JSON objects in POST request like this example:

```
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.loginEntry  = new Object();
    obj.loginEntry.userid = username;
    obj.loginEntry.password = password;
    var data = Ext.JSON.encode(obj);
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'http://myservice/endpoint',
        method : "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        params : data,
        useDefaultXhrHeader : false,
        withCredentials: true,
        success : function(response) {
            console.log(response.responseText);
        }
    });
```

After all this gyan, I'd still recommend not to use `POST` for read because as per convention it should write not read. As per REST convention your read only service should be GET and it should follow construct like:

```
http://localhost/noobapis/api/bill/{userid}/outstanding/{locations_csv}/....
```

OR

```
http://localhost/noobapis/api/bill/outstanding?userid={userid}&location={locations_separed_by_delimeter}
```

Comment: first - i am not making an explicit ajax call. I just have a store configured with a proxy. This is specifically about using ' http get + store.load() + json proxy '. I already know about the possibilities of an explicit ajax call (new Ext.Ajax.Request ...). but i would prefer not to go that way, unless no other options exist. it would require changing my entire model/store/proxy convention throughout the app.

Comment: second, the sample given above is simplified, i've removed other parameters other than id and locations, but they exist and they are objects, not primitives or arrays.

last, i dont really want to use post for a read. I just want the ability to pass a complex type to a 'get' endpoint when it is being used in conjunction with a store and json proxy. If i have a 3 level deep nested object as the argument, how does this fit in with the store + proxy + 'get' mode of operation?

Comment: Whether sencha or non-sencha how do you send nested object to `GET` service? You only have option of url params & header (because there is no body) and both takes string data, so max you can do is to flatten your object in JSON string and send it. If you want to use store & proxy approach, you can create `proxy` object with whatever `url` & `extraParams` and set it to your store like this : `myStore.setProxy( myCustomProxy )` before calling load().

Comment: yes, my problem exactly. because my endpoint will require an argument of this sort. and thus in this case i was thinking it makes sense to change the operation to post. the problem is, i can't find a way to add the custom data to the proxy defined by the store. i'll try the post + extraParams options and see how that works out. thx.

Comment: Okay, so how did it go? Any success?

Comment: BTW if you are using POST you should use `params` instead of `extraParams`.

Comment: cant use params in touch 2.0. But extraParams puts the data in request body automatically when using post. marking answer as accepted. thx.